# Calculate the image it's width in every div(with same class)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my Jquery code to calculate the image it's width in every div. For example: When the images it's width is bigger than 250, I want to give the text next to it a clear:both so it goes beneath the image instead of next to it. Here's an example of my HTML and Jquery:

```
<div class="tile-wrapper-test">
                        <div id="category-text">
                            <p class="category-content">Smartphones / software</p>
                        </div>                        
                            <div class="tile-image-test">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/wp10.jpg" class="tile-image" name="title" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="title-text-test">
                                <a href="#" class="title-text">text text text text text text</a>
                            </div>
                        <div id="date-time-text">
                            <p class="date-time">3 minutes ago.</p>  
                        </div>
                    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".title-text-test").each(function () {
            imageWidth = $('.tile-image-test').width();
            $(".title-text-test").width(imageWidth);
            if (imageWidth  > 250) {
                $(".title-text-test").addClass('clr');
            }
        });
    });
```

[Gyazo screenshot](http://gyazo.com/151fd2b87f842e36e2e43341f59be100)
What it does now is, that it only calculates the first div it's width and not the second etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `each` function you're getting a reference to all the `.title-txt-test` objects again, instead of using the one being operated on by the function. Try changing your `$(".title-text-test")` selectors inside the `each` function to `this`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".title-text-test").each(function () {
        imageWidth = $(this).closest('.tile-image-test').width();
        $(this).width(imageWidth);
        if (imageWidth  > 250) {
            $(this).addClass('clr');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must calculate the width on the element that pass through the callback function `$(this)`

```
$('.tile-image-test').each( function( index ) {
  console.log( 'Width for image ' + index + ' is ' + $( this ).width() + 'px' );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

You are setting class `clr` to all elements that has class `title-text-test`, because You are getting `width()` of first element (imageWidth = $('.tile-image-test').width();), you should pass params to `.each()` callback function something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".title-text-test").each(function (index, element) {
        imageWidth = $(element).closest('.tile-image-test').width(); // select closest image
        $(element).width(imageWidth);
        if (imageWidth  > 250) {
            $(element).addClass('clr');
        }
    });
});
```

For more detailed answer, please provide us with Your html

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the parameter 'element' u gave me and also I've provided my html. @Bogdan